# Why i see 0.2% change in validation score when i use just 100 samples for validation

Tags: keras, deep-learning

I created a deep learning model with 400 samples for training and 100 samples for validation.
Since I have exactly 100 validation samples, I expect that the validation score should only change in 1% steps. I mean, when the model has **one** wrong prediction, the validation accuracy should be 99%. But I get 0.2% steps - for example I have 99.8% accuracy in epoch 6.

Here are some of my epochs.

```
Epoch 1/50
7/7 [==============================] - 38s 4s/step - loss: 1.7120 - acc: 0.6757 - val_loss: 1.1954 - val_acc: 0.8460

Epoch 2/50
7/7 [==============================] - 21s 3s/step - loss: 1.1830 - acc: 0.9484 - val_loss: 1.0480 - val_acc: 0.9760

Epoch 3/50
7/7 [==============================] - 20s 3s/step - loss: 0.9788 - acc: 0.9973 - val_loss: 0.8467 - val_acc: 1.0000

Epoch 4/50
7/7 [==============================] - 20s 3s/step - loss: 0.8315 - acc: 0.9994 - val_loss: 0.6995 - val_acc: 1.0000

Epoch 5/50
7/7 [==============================] - 20s 3s/step - loss: 0.7167 - acc: 1.0000 - val_loss: 0.6072 - val_acc: 1.0000

Epoch 6/50
7/7 [==============================] - 20s 3s/step - loss: 0.6138 - acc: 1.0000 - val_loss: 0.5310 - val_acc: 0.9980
```

The same problem exists with train accuracy. I fit the model using this command in Keras.

```
history = model.fit(np.array(X_train),np.array(Y_train),epochs=50, batch_size=64, validation_data = (np.array(X_test),np.array(Y_test)), shuffle=True)
```

Have I misunderstood the accuracy calculation?

Comment: please show your model code

Comment: Do you think it's about the model?

Comment: e.g. if your model is RNN - then accuracy is calculated based on the number of tokens not on the number of samples

Comment: I think it's about average. In each epoch, accuracy will be calculated on the different batches and the average of all accuracies is shown as the final accuracy of the epoch. But I am not sure :|

Comment: Yes, it's a CNN-LSTM model. I don't know about tokens I am working on EEG signals.

Answer (score 1):

If your model is RNN - then accuracy is calculated based on the number of sequence elements not on the number of samples.

In your case - accuracy is calculated as number of correct signals divided by number of total signals.